# Getting list elements satisfying some criteria using a comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list like this:

```
foolist = ['foo   bar', 'foo', 'bar' 'foo bar']
```

I want the number of `foo`s in that list, without using regex. Is there a simpler way to do it than below, using one line?

```
print(len([i for i in [ 'foo' in line for line in foolist ] if i == True]))
```

The above is interesting, but it also makes my skin crawl in the way that nested ternary operators would.

Comment: `[i for i in foolist if 'foo' in i]`?

Comment: You might want to rethink the `'foo' in line` test you're using, since it will be true for any string that contains that sequence, regardless of the context.  For example, it will match `'my left foot'`, since `'foot'` contains `'foo'`.  Is that what you want?  How about strings that contain multiple instances, do you only want to count them once?  E.g. do you want `'foo bar foo baz'` to count as one match, as your code does, or do you want to count it as two?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I think that was I trying to do originally but couldn't quite figure out.

Comment: @TomKarzes yeah, I agree, was more interested in pithiness over accuracy in this case.

Comment: @Lucky In the world of computers, details are everything.  If the details aren't known, the code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little shorter: use `map` to transform `foolist` to a list of 1's and 0', then `sum` them up:

```
sum(map(lambda x: 1 if 'foo' in x else 0, foolist))
```

Update: or even shorter:

```
len(tuple(filter(lambda x: 'foo' in x, foolist)))
```

My brain finds comprehensions incomprehensible when they are not simple so I move on to map/reduce/filter functions :)

UPDATE: Added `tuple` since in Python3, `len` can't count an iterator.

Comment: These are very useful for Pythonic style, thanks!

Comment: What version are you using for the latter one? I'm getting `TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()` on 3.6.8

Comment: It worked in 2.7 (i support some old code).  Looks like in 3.x, the results of `filter` need to be converted to a `list` or `tuple` for `len` to work.  I'll update the answer.